# Can't access the Value in PHP array via index

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to access the element of associative array but its giving the error of undefined index . I have made sure that my index is correct and the code is written fine but it's adding an alphabet 'A' at end of index 'Genre' by itself. i don't know where it is coming from . Below is the code,the error and the dump :

```
if($Row){
    $Data = unserialize($Row->Data);
    $Last = array();
    unset($Path[0]);
    foreach($Path as $Key=>$name){
        echo $name;
        $Last = $Data[$name];
    }
    return $Last;
}
```

Error that i got

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Undefined index: GenreA (View: C:\xampp\htdocs......)

```
dd($Data,$Path);
```

Gives :

```
array:7 [▼
    "Regions" => array:10 [▶]
    "Country" => array:241 [▶]
    "Languages" => array:106 [▶]
    "Category" => array:2 [▶]
    "SubCategory" => array:2 [▶]
    "Genre" => array:2 [▶]
    "SubGenre" => array:2 [▶]
] 

array:1 [▼
    1 => "Genre"
]
```

[image]

Debug image
[image]

Comment: 'GenreA' is not an index, it's a value. the index of that value is '1'

Comment: but its index of $Data ...see dump image

Comment: in dump image $data array has only one 'key value pair'. '1' is the key 'Genre' is the value.

Comment: You are seeing the $Path dump

Comment: @TharakaDilshan The OP is trying to use the values in `$Path` as keys for `$Data`.

Comment: its in pattern dd($Data,$Path);

Comment: You've posted that you used `dd($data, $path)` while your code uses `$Date` and `$Path`. Is it just a typo here on SO?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no its not the typo.

Comment: @ArsiiRasheed It was before you edited it. Please remember we can only comment on the code you show us. We are not clairvoyant!

Comment: Is the above code all the code that you have, or have you rewritten or changed it for us here? Is it an actual copy/paste? There's no reason for that code to throw that error. Demo: https://3v4l.org/PJiVe

Comment: i have copy pasted the chunk .

Comment: You should use the `$key` to access the indexes not the `$name` in your case, so try to change your code to this: `$Last = $Data[$key]`;
Also, Please post full code if it possible.

Comment: @HAßdøµ - That's what the OP already has? Also, the OP is trying to use the _value_ from one array as the _key_ in the other array. The code actually works.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  Sorry for the mistake, I changed it now.

Comment: debugger image is added

Comment: @RiggsFolly see the debugger image added later .

Comment: Well `GenreA` does not exist in `$data` so how are you getting a `A` added to that field?

Comment: @RiggsFolly thats the point i am unable to get ... where 'A' is comming from .. first time seen such error

Comment: What does the `echo $name` show?

Comment: @RiggsFolly shows 'Genre'

Comment: Then I would start looking for invisible characters that have been added to your `$Path` array. How do you load the `$Path` array

Comment: $key= "Listing.Genre"; and function is public static function GetItem($Key){
        $Path = explode('.',$Key);.....} this is how $Path is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think don't need for each loop just write like this I hope it will work

```
end($Data);  
$last = key($Data);  
$last_element = $Data[$last];
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on the help pages